# Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed with ganymed-ssh-2 and Cisco Confd

Tags: ssh, netconf, confd

I am using JNC 1.0 & ganymed-ssh-2 v262 to establish a Netconf session over SSH to a Cisco Confd node and getting the following error. What could be the reason?

java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:75)
at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:169)
at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:759)
at com.tailf.jnc.SSHConnection.(Unknown Source)
at com.tailf.jnc.Device.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.tailf.jnc.Device.connect(Unknown Source)
....
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot negotiate, proposals do not match.
at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.ClientKexManager.handleMessage(ClientKexManager.java:123)
at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:572)
at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:261)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Answer (score 1):

```
java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.

...
...

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot negotiate, proposals do not match.
```

It means that there is a mismatch between the supported key exchange algorithms on the client and those supported by the server.

I'd advice to update `ganymed-ssh-2` to [v263](https://github.com/SoftwareAG/ganymed-ssh-2/releases/tag/ganymed-ssh2-263). Apparently the latest version has added support for the following kex algorithms:

```
diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
```

You can check what the server supports by using ssh's debug flag on a terminal:

```
ssh -vvv user@host
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I downloaded the ganymed-ssh2-263-sources.jar and added to my project's build path. The problem resolved now.  Source: https://github.com/SoftwareAG/ganymed-ssh-2/releases/tag/ganymed-ssh2-263

Comment: @Mohan There is a better way to say thanks. If this answer solved your problem, mark it as an answer by clicking the tickmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. As suggested, we upgraded to `ganymed-ssh-2-build263.jar` and still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

the SSH hostkey were not matching in confd.
we copied the keys again and then it started to work

```
cp -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub /opt/confd/etc/confd/ssh
```